# Rcpp: unable to load shared object, undefined symbol

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I'm trying to use Rcpp to extend functionality from the [BayesOpt](http://rmcantin.bitbucket.org/html/) C++ library into R.  I'm a long-time R user but relatively new to C++ and I'm running into some problems. I've followed the Rcpp vignettes for setting up a package, which I understand is the best way to bring external C++ libraries in.

I've set PKG_CPPFLAGS and PKG_LIBS in src/Makevars to the BayesOpt include folders and library, and I have a single .cpp file (call it test.cpp) in src/ that uses #include for some header files from BayesOpt.  In this file, I have `// [[Rcpp::export]]` above the function I want to export.

When I run `R CMD check mypackage`, the library seems to be working successfully -- looking at the log, everything goes well until it tries to load the package that was just "installed".  Then, I get

```
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/me/p3/mypackage.Rcheck/mypackage/libs/mypackage.so':
   /home/me/p3/mypackage.Rcheck/mypackage/libs/mypackage.so: undefined symbol: _ZTIN8bayesopt13DiscreteModelE
```

in the error log.  `echo _ZTIN8bayesopt13DiscreteModelE | c++filt` gives `typeinfo for bayesopt::DiscreteModel`, which is the first object in my test.cpp file that uses the BayesOpt headers.  I've looked high and low for a solution to this, but I can't seem to find one.  I would like to believe that the Makevars points at the library correctly, because it is able to find the header files during the first installation check -- it's only when loading the candidate package that I get this undefined symbol error.  I've looked at an Rcpp example that uses external libraries, but the one Dirk points to in the answers I've looked at, `RcppGSL`, has a 3500+ line configure script that fills out the Makevars, and it's a little difficult to parse.

I would appreciate anyone's help -- my last resort is to dump everything into `src` but that seems cumbersome and less than elegant for a library that is already neatly organized.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't look at the `configure` script which is auto-generated -- look at `configure.ac` which is its source, and which is all of 5 lines which matter (see below) plus maybe 5 lines of setup and finish.

And in a nutshell, you may just need to load values for both headers (via `-I...`) and linking (via `-L... -l...`).

And for that we do this in `src/Makevars.in`:

```
# set by configure
GSL_CFLAGS = @GSL_CFLAGS@
GSL_LIBS   = @GSL_LIBS@

# combine with standard arguments for R
PKG_CPPFLAGS = $(GSL_CFLAGS) -I../inst/include
PKG_LIBS = $(GSL_LIBS)
```

The two variables denoted by `@GSL...@` are both set via `configure` and `configure.ac` (in essence) just calls `gsl-config` after asserting that we have it:

```
## Use gsl-config to find arguments for compiler and linker flags
##
## Check for non-standard programs: gsl-config(1)
AC_PATH_PROG([GSL_CONFIG], [gsl-config])
## If gsl-config was found, let's use it
if test "${GSL_CONFIG}" != ""; then
    # Use gsl-config for header and linker arguments
    GSL_CFLAGS=`${GSL_CONFIG} --cflags`
    GSL_LIBS=`${GSL_CONFIG} --libs`
else
    AC_MSG_ERROR([gsl-config not found, is GSL installed?])
fi
```

Many other libraries created in the last decade or so use a similar (but more generic) tool called `pkg-config` which serves the same purpose: communicate the compile and linker flags to programs using the library.

And you **do** need both, your comment

> I would like to believe that the Makevars points at the library correctly, because it is able to find the header files during the first installation check

indicates you have the *compilation* sorted out but *not* the linking or maybe not the system provision of your library.  Again, for RcppGSL the final line during build is the following (edited for brevity)

```
g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -o RcppGSL.so \
 RcppExports.o fastLm.o setErrorHandler.o \
 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lgsl -lgslcblas \
 -lm -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
```

It links three source files with two GSL-related libraries as well with R and the math library. You must see something similar in your build, or it is not correctly setup.

*Edit:* And if you bundle BayesOpt in your package, then you need to build it into a *static* library and list that in the `src/Makevars`.  That is a different use case: for RcppGSL we look for a *system* GSL installation.  Local is different.  You could study the nloptr package which deals with both cases.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and thorough response, Dirk.  Before I continue down either path -- is there a "best practice" with respect to bundling C++ source code as a static library vs. looking for a system installation when developing R packages with Rcpp?  Is it perhaps more practical to look for system installations when the C++ library is more "common"?

Comment: Exactly.  When working with a more specialised library you often have to bundle it.  A little more work,  a little longer compile time, but you then are in fact self-contained.

Comment: OK, I've decided to build it into a static library.  A few follow-ups: 1.  Should I be building and installing the static library into `mypackage/inst` or `mypackage/src`, practice-wise?  2.  Either way, when I run `R CMD check mypackage`, I also get the warning that libraries should not be included in a source package.  Is this warning irrelevant to my use case?

Comment: Please take this discussion to the r-package-devel list, after re-reading "Writing R Extensions". This is not the place or time for one-on-one tutorials.

Comment: Will do, thanks.  I do think that S/O is a great place to disseminate knowledge, and I will likely post my full solution here once I figure it out.  This will help the next person with a similar problem avoid having to dig through the roughly interfaced R list archives and hopefully save a lot of researchers a lot of time.  I know most people prefer getting quick help over S/O than going through an email list.  We all appreciate the numerous times you have provided help!

Comment: There is a way to acknowledge a good and helpful answer: upvote (click on up arrow), and if yo are the asked it, accept (click on tickmark).

Comment: @user2476581 Just wondering if you were able to package your code into a static library and if yes, is there any place I can take a look at the code. That will help me a lot! Thanks!